# Selecting dropdown using protractor

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, protractor, semantic-ui

I have a simple SEMANTIC UI gender select dropdown that I have to test with protractor. I am not able to find a way to click it as $,by.model(),findelement() and many such attributes are not available for angular 2 for testing. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="field ">
              <label for="gender" class="asterisk">Gender</label>
                <select class="ui dropdown" formControlName="gender" id="gender" name="gender" required>
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="Male" >Male</option>
              <option value="Female" id="Female">Female</option>
         </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it using browser.action() method. follow the below code:

```
var drpOpt=element(by.css("option[value='Male']"))//change the value to Female 
 //if you want to select Female
element(by.name("gender")).click().then(function(){
browser.actions().mouseMove(drpOpt).click().perform();
});
```

Comment: hi suresh, with this I am still getting 'element not visible' error. any workaround?

Comment: I am using semantic UI dropdown, which uses jquery and not html select dropdown. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
element(by.name('gender')).element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Male')).click();
```